# Use mathematical induction to prove that $2^n<n!$ for every integer n with $n\geq4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have done basic steps for $p(4)$ and $p(4)$ is true because $2^4 = 16<24 = 4!$
Now i have to show the statement is true for $n+1$

Comment: I am sure you can solve this yourself if you look through your course notes again....

Comment: Suppose that it's true for $n$. Can you show that it's true for $n+1$? Please edit your question to show any work you've done towards this, even if it seems to not go anywhere.

Comment: @Riquelme yeah i have solved it just 2min ago i have done some mistake that's why i was not able to  solve it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction step is:

If $2^n<n!$ then $2^{n+1}<2\cdot n!\le(n+1)!$ for $n+1\ge2$.

Comment: Thanks for help.  I have done n! instead of 2.n! so i got confuse

Comment: @Gone $2^{n+1}=2\times 2^n$, and we are assuming $2^n<n!$, so $2^{n+1}<2\times n!$

Comment: yeah i get that Thanks for help!